# Delete cannot erase chars under the cursor on my terminal

Tags: terminal, tty, erase

Instead, I get a ~ character. But I have set the delete key as follows:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 47; columns 91; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = ^Z; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany
imaxbel
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -tostop echoctl echoke
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one key on your keyboard which might be called "delete".  Some (by convention) send a single byte (which is what `stty` deals with) and others may send a multi-byte (escape) sequence.  Typically you deal with the latter using the terminal database, e.g., using ncurses (as well as termcap- and terminfo-interfaces to the terminal database).

Some aspects of this are in the xterm FAQ: [Why doesn't my delete key work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_erase)